# Was Titan once warmed by a hot Saturn, & therefore much more Earth-like than it is today?

Tags: astrophysics, thermal-radiation, estimation, solar-system

Is it possible that 4 billion years ago, Saturn was sufficiently hot to act as a second sun to Titan, so that conditions on Titan were then similar to those on Earth?

Comment: Is there anything that leads you to believe that this is possible?

Comment: We know that when the planets were formed,Earth for example,they were very hot,incandescent in fact. By 4 billion years ago they had cooled,but the gas giants would still have been very hot. Jupiter,for example,is not much different from a brown dwarf,which is a kind of failed sun where there was not enough mass for fusion reactions to take place. Saturn has similarities to Jupiter,but is considerable smaller. We know it was hotter 4 billon years ago,but was it hot enough to act as a second sun?

Answer (score 3):

*Could Titan have been warmed by Saturn as a "second Sun" at the beginning of the solar system?*

To make the conditions "similar to Earth", Titan would need to receive as much radiation from Saturn as the Earth gets now from the Sun $j=1368\ \mathrm{\frac{W}{m^{2}}}$

Knowing this, and considering the simplest model for heat radiation (black body) we can use the Stefan–Boltzmann equation to calculate at what temperature Saturn needed to be (we need to check if it is a reasonable and attainable temperature for a planet).

Because we are considering the simplest model, we can approximate the radiation from Saturn as if it were emitted from a circle (the projected area, i.e., the area seen from Titan) of area $\pi R_{\text{Saturn}}^{2}$

The area that receives this heat is $1\ \mathrm{m^2}$ and at a distance of $1\,221\,850\ \mathrm{km}$ I calculated the solid angle (the fraction of the $4\pi$ units of area of a sphere) to be $6.70\times10^{-19}\ \mathrm{sr}$ which means that $1\ \mathrm{m^2}$ of surface in Titan receives a very small $1.066 \times10^{-19}$ part of the total energy radiated from the circle (I divided by $2\pi$, the surface of half a sphere, because I was considering that the circle radiates over a half sphere). We can now proceed to calculate the approximate temperature of Saturn:

$$1368\ \mathrm{\frac{W}{m^{2}}}=(1.066 \times10^{-19})(\sigma T_\text{Saturn}^4)(\pi R_\text{Saturn}^{2})$$

The first factor on the right is the fraction of the radiation received by Titan. The second factor is the heat emitted from Saturn per unit of area and the third factor is the effective area emitting radiation towards Titan. Also, we get the second factor from the Stefan–Boltzmann law.

Solving for $T$ we get:

$$T_\text{Saturn}=\sqrt[4]{\frac{1368\ \mathrm{W\ m^{-2}}}{(1.066 \times10^{-19}\ \mathrm{m^{-2}})(5.6704\times10^{-8}\ \mathrm{W\ m^{-2}\ K^{-4}})(1.065\times10^{16}\ \mathrm{m^2})}}$$

The resulting temperature is $T_\text{Saturn}=2147\ \mathrm K = 1874\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$

It seems reasonable (the temperature of the surface of the sun is about $6000\ \mathrm K$ but Saturn is much closer to Titan than the Sun is to the Earth), but we would need to check if these temperatures ever happened in the outer solar system. I found this document (it seems like an exam from some class) that suggests that they did not:

---

[image]

---

As you can see there, the temperature of Saturn was much closer to the $100\ \mathrm K$ than it was to $2000\ \mathrm K$. **The bottom line is that it probably did not happen, and if it did it would have been very brief.**

Comment: As a side note: If we consider the radiation that actually reaches the surface of the Earth (around $1000 W/m^2$) we get a smaller estimate of $1985 K$ (still too high for the outer solar system), but Titan does have a dense atmosphere... so I thought it was better to use the 1368.